# Integrate CalDAV to Android Outlook

Tags: calendar, outlook, caldav

Is it possible to integrate the CalDAV calendar into the Android Outlook app?

Usually, CalDAV calendars don’t appear in the Android Outlook app, so I search for a way to integrate CalDAV into Outlook. I know there is a software called [Outlook CalDav Synchronizer](https://caldavsynchronizer.org/) but it's only for desktop (Windows).

There is another app called [DAVx5](https://www.davx5.com/) to synchronize CalDAV, but it's a paid app and I don't want to waste it.

Does someone have the experience?

Comment: 1) DAVx5 is definitely no waste, and 2) it's available for free on F-Droid. So if the Outlook app can show entries from your Android calendars (I cannot tell, as I don't waste my time and data on such apps), then syncing your CalDAV calendars with DAVx5 will solve this for you.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP's account doesn't exist anymore, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Outlook for Android does not support the CalDAV feature so far. There was a feature request on the deprecated [Outlook UserVoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20200918233926/https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/9737451-add-caldav-support-for-calendar) (archived since [Microsoft has moved away from UserVoice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uservoice-pages-430e1a78-e016-472a-a10f-dc2a3df3450a)).