# CardDAV and Outlook for Android

Tags: contacts, outlook

Is there a way to get contact from a CardDAV server (Radicale) into Outlook on Android?
I'm aware of DAVx5 and it seems to work fine on my phone. I can use this to see CalDAV calendars in Outlook but I haven't found a way to integrate the contacts from CardDAV. I see the contact in the normal contacts app but not in outlook.
Am I missing something or is this not possible?
Which would be a pity as Outlook seems to be the only tool which integrates email, contacts and calendar.

Comment: Related (but probably not a dupe) since the answer acknowledged that Outlook doesn't support CalDAV (yet): [Integrate CalDAV to Android Outlook](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225125/44325)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. Yes i saw this and a similar question but this only addresses CalDAV which you can integrate via DAVx5 with Outlook but not CardDAV :(